# Struts 2 validation resets my dynamic data

Tags: validation, struts, reset, dynamic-data

I'm trying to validate a form and it works well, the right messages appear...
My only problem is that my form fields are deleted if there are some errors.

Datas are taken by Database and be showed in forms with struts tags (so they're dynamic). If I put sono static value, that will not deleted after a wrong validation.

```
     <s:form action="updateUser" method="post" id="updateUser"
    name="updateUser" >     

    <s:textfield value="%{user.name}" class="modify"  id="name" name="name" key="modify.name" required="true"    />
```

this will be deleted while this:

```
<s:textfield value="HELLO" class="modify"  id="name" name="name" key="modify.name" required="true"    />
```

will not.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set a User object in your Action Class? Do you have getters/setters for that object?  Also how have you configured the "input" result of this action in struts.xml? Maybe you should use "chain" in result of INPUT (i guess this is the result you get from the validator.)

Comment: Yeah, I've create the object with Get and Set. The object in fact is correctly displayed, in struts.xml I've put INPUT type result as well.
  
It seems a struts problem, because If I put static data it will works with no field reset.

Comment: Try:  <s:textfield value="%{user.name}" class="modify"  id="name" name="user.name" key="modify.name" required="true"    />

Comment: Yeah it works!! Thanks!
Just a thing: If I rename in user.name, I've to change xml validator, and setter/getter, so I find a smart way:

<s:set var="name" value="%{user.name}" />

<s:textfield value="%{name}" class="modify"  id="name" name="name" key="modify.name" required="true"    />